# When do I need to use a brewing Kettle?

Tags: malt, brewing, kettle, beginner

A lot of recipes mention using a brewing kettle to make the wort. Is this necessary, or can I just add liquid malt directly to my primary fermentor carboy? I don't have a place to boil the wort.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a pre-hopped extract, no boil brewing is possible. All extracts have already been boiled by the manufacturer anyways; with extracts, the main purpose behind boiling is you need the higher temperatures to cause isomerization of the hop acids so the hop bitterness gets into the beer. Secondary reasons for boiling extracts are additional protein coagulation, removing chloramines (when using tap water), and just extra assurance of sanitation for the paranoid among us.

Personally I'd never do a no boil beer, as it would inhibit my ability to relax, not worry and have a homebrew. But it can result in quality, even [award winning](http://byo.com/stories/item/556-dont-boil-it) beer. Just be extra vigilant with your sanitation procedures.

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree with dax, it really depends what you are making. If you are in fact making a cider you might not want to boil it to utilise the wild yeast that is present on the peel of the fruit.

If you are reading a recipe that is specifically mentioning your malt extract (or brewing kit) and it mentions that you need to boil it, then it probably means that it is not pre-boiled and it needs to be sanitised by boiling it.

If you are looking to make beer without boiling anything I would suggest searching for beer kits that are labelled "No Boil" (for instance; `Coopers Brewmaster Selection India Pale Ale No Boil Home Brew Beer Kit`).

Although, in order to add your own personal touch to a brew I would definitely recommend boiling, since you are then able to control all the parameters; malt-flavours, hops-flavours, bitterness etc.

Good luck brewing!

Answer (score 2):

This really depends what you're making - if you're making mead or cider, you don't have to boil anything (and I would argue you shouldn't although that's up for debate with some).  Some kits don't need to be boiled as per their instructions - and this is probably what you have.  You can mix the tin of goo with some hot water directly in your fermenter and go from there.

However if you work your way up to all grain, you will need to boil.

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about beer, I would say that it isn't worth doing unless the end product is going to be good, and you will likely be disappointed by a hopped extract kit.

if you are doing this as sort of an experiment rather than to have loads of great beer, then there is no harm in trying... but don't think that you are bad at brewing because the sauce you reconstituted didn't turn into great beer.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned some cool =, intresting facts.
My contribution is this.
all the recipes I've made have 2 sets of boiling instructions, full and partial boil. the partial boils are for 2 to 3 gallons. this can be done on your kitchen stove easily enough. 
hopefully this will encourage you to give it a shot.